# Docker Asp.net core app won't load my JS, imgs

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker

I have an asp.net core app which runs fine when Published.  I'm deploying it to a docker image with the following series of commands, [lifted whole cloth from this MSFT guide.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container)

```
docker build -t myimage -f Dockerfile .
docker images
docker create myimage
docker run -it -p 5000:80 -d myimage
```

Here's the Dockerfile I use to compose the image, btw.

```
#Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0
COPY /bin/Release/netcoreapp3.0/publish/. app/
EXPOSE 80 443 5000 5001
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/KittenSignalR.dll"]
```

I can connect to the site from a browser but only the view files themselves are served, with JS, images, etc not loading.
[image]

All other assets show this error in the Chrome console.

```
GET http://localhost:5000/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

However, when I check my container itself through bash, I can see all of the content, just that it's not being served.

```
docker exec -i -t 46263b09f1 /bin/bash
root@46263b09f1d3:/# cd app/wwwroot/js
root@46263b09f1d3:/app/wwwroot/js# ls
Class.cs  chat.js  signalr  site.js
```

Any tips?

Startup.cs from my app

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on removing the file , I checked and the wwwroot/lib/bootstrap path does exist in the container.

Comment: I am, editing in my app's startup config.  If I were to run the same app from Windows, all content is loaded correctly.  it's only when run in docker with the entrypoint of `'dotnet', 'app/myApp.dll'` that the content isn't loaded.

Comment: Would you mind contributing this as an answer so you can get the credit you deserve?  That was my issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: your working directory is `/`, it needs to be `/app`.

---

When you serve static files with ASP.Net Core, Microsoft says this:

> The app's web host must be made aware of the content root directory.
>
> The WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder method sets the content root **to the current directory**

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-static-files), emphasis mine.

Looking at your Dockerfile, you never change the working directory, so it stays the same as the base image you derive it from (the `aspnet:3.0` image)<sup>1</sup>.

Because your working directory is `/`, the application is looking for a `wwwroot` folder (essentially `/wwwroot`), which it can't find. That's the reason you get a 404 on all your wwwroot assets.

To fix this, just change the working directory of the Docker image and update the entrypoint to use a relative path from that WD.

```
#Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0
COPY /bin/Release/netcoreapp3.0/publish/. app/
EXPOSE 80 443 5000 5001
WORKDIR app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "KittenSignalR.dll"]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It's worth bringing up that you're copying files to, and setting the working directory to, `app`. That's a relative directory path, and I HIGHLY recommend that you make it absolute (`/app`).

I'm *assuming* that the `aspnet:3.0` image has a default working directory of `/`, but I can't be sure.

Leaving it relative means that you are basing your folder structure off of the base image's default working directory. It *could* be the root, or it might not. Better to make absolute (pun intended) sure and make it an absolute path.

```
#Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0
COPY /bin/Release/netcoreapp3.0/publish/. /app/
EXPOSE 80 443 5000 5001
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "KittenSignalR.dll"]
```